# Nested CSS ids will work in firefox, but not IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have html nested like so

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="asection">
        <h1>Some Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

With css properies as follows

```
h1 {
color:#873C62;
font-size:32px;
line-height:26px;
}

#asection {
width:430px;
height:100%;
color:#666666;
font-size:12px;
line-height:17px;
}

#content {
width:968px;
clear:both;
padding:30px;
height:1%; overflow:hidden; 
}
```

This displays as intended in all browsers except Internet Explorer 7/8

I'm still getting the hang of CSS and browser compatibility so any extra eyes/expertise is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
I made a property

```
#asection .h1 {}
```

and put the same things from the original h1 and it worked.
I corrected a typo I made with h1 and h7 as well, that was my mistake when i was trying to make my markup generic.

Comment: h7? but the markup has an h1 and i think it only goes to h6

Comment: Can you say what results you're getting, and how they differ from your expectations?

Comment: The code as posted gives the same result in both IE8 and Firefox for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for the `.`  just put a space before `h1`  the dot points to a class and unless you have a class named `h1`  i.e. *`class="h1"`*  then this will not work as intended,

so if you are trying to target the h1 within `#asection`  here's the code:

```
#asection h1 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#asection .h1 {}
```

The period before the h1 indicates a class called "h1", not an element. To target the element h1 just specify it as is.

This should work the same in both Firefox and IE8; there should be no difference in this respect.